# setlistAdapter is not Working

Tags: android

My Adapter

```
public class FlowerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Flower> 
{

    private Context context;

    private List<Flower> flowerlist;

    public FlowerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Flower> objects){
        super(context,resource,objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.flowerlist=objects;


    }

    public  View getView(int position,View convertView ,ViewGroup parent){

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   

       context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


       View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.items ,parent,false);

       Flower flower = flowerlist.get(position);

       TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text2);

       tv.setText(flower.getName());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Display in list view

```
FlowerAdapter flowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(Getdata.this ,   R.layout.items,flowers);

//setListAdapter(flowerAdapter);
```

Comment: Can you at least add a stacktrace and describe the actions you've already tried?

Comment: The method is not `setListAdapter` but `setAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your activity class is not a list activity, that might be your problem

make sure you are inheriting from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`

```
public class YourActivity extends ListActivity {
 setListAdapter(flowerAdapter);
}
```

Meanwhile in case you don't want to use/extend from `ListActivity` you could easily add `ListView` inside your activity, and set it like below without changing your activity class inheritance.

```
listView.setAdapter(flowerAdapter);
```